# How can I change textsize in customlistview?

Tags: android, listview

I searched answer and find similar one.But I can't understand.
I want to change my customlistview's textSize when I clikced Optionmenu.
I found that I have to change my customadapter's getView method.
But I can not understand...

I tried code like

MyAdapter.textView.setTextSize();

But it just workd one list...

I want to change whole my customlistview.

It had 4 textView...
Help please.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to get the BaseAdapter and modify font size in its getView() call.

Comment: How can I call getView  ?? Do I have to make My baseadapter class innerclass?

Comment: @Andro_new http://www.softwarepassion.com/?s=Android&x=0&y=0 check this link for your reference. You need to use custom Adapter.